# Cry in salat fardhu

Tags: salat

I saw someone who cry in his salat. I saw him cry too much that make me doubt about his salat.
 Are there some information which allow this??

Salam, 
Ahmad

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is ok to cry in Salat whether it is fardh or not (out of khushu'/خشية of Allah).  There is no such thing as crying/weeping too much in salat if it is done out of khushu'/خشية of Allah.  Furthermore there is no authentic proof which **disallows** it, and Allah knows best.

> أَتَيْتُ النَّبِيَّ صلى الله عليه وسلم وَهُوَ يُصَلِّي وَلِجَوْفِهِ
>   أَزِيزٌ كَأَزِيزِ الْمِرْجَلِ يَعْنِي يَبْكِي
>
> I came to the Prophet (sallallahu 'alaihi wa sallam) when he was
>   praying, and there was a sound coming from his chest like the sound of
>   water boiling," meaning, he was weeping.

[Sunan Annasa'i](http://sunnah.com/nasai/13/36)